# Retrieve name of foreign key using Eloquent

Tags: php, sql, laravel

```
public function update(Request $request, Currency $currency)
{
    $validData = $request->validate([
        'name' => 'required',
    ]);

    $currency->name = $request ['name'];

    $currency->symbol_url = Image::uploadFileToS3($request, 'symbol_url', $company->name . '/currency/');

    $currency->save();

    return redirect('company');
}
```

I'm trying to do the update method of the currency controller.

Because of the S3 path, I need to pass down the company name.

The currency already have a company id associated as a foreign key, how can i do the query?

Comment: By programming it. SO is a problem-solving community, not a free coding service. Try some stuff and see where it gets you. Then come back if you have a specific question or problem we can answer.

Comment: $company->name= Currency::find($company)->first($company->name); tried this, but i have a sense that this is 101% wrong

The thing is, i can find with no problems values within the same table, im just having trouble on how to fetch data from foreign keys

Answer (score 0):

$currency->company->name

It was pretty simple, i was complicating it a lot..

The above answer retrieves the company name for that currency.